# Classification of fibrations for classifying spaces $B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $BSO(3)$ or $BO(3)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-groups, characteristic-classes, fibre-bundles, classifying-spaces

I am interested in knowing what can we say about the classification of fibrations for classifying spaces $B^2M \equiv B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $BG \equiv BSO(3)$ or $BO(3)$.

Here we can take either:

1. $B^2M=B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ as fibers, and $BG=BSO(3)$ (or $BO(3)$) as base manifold.

or

2. $BG=BSO(3)$ (or $BO(3)$)   as fibers, and $B^2M=B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ as base manifold.

For example,

**(A)** We consider the  Postinikov classes $\omega \in H^3(BG,M)$. This classifies the fibrations of
$$
B^2M \hookrightarrow BG_\text{{new}} \to BG.
$$
If I understand correctly, the distinct $BG_\text{{new}}$ are determined by the classes of cocycles $\omega \in H^3(BG,M)$.

**(B)** On the other hand, we have $1\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to O(3) \to SO(3) \to 1$, this gives rise $B\mathbb{Z}_2 \to BO(3) \to BSO(3) \to B^2\mathbb{Z}_2,$
$$
 BO(3) \to BSO(3) \to B^2\mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
which seems to suggest a fibration of $BO(3)$ over $B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$

**(C)** On the other hand, we further have $1\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to SU(2) \to SO(3) \to 1$, this gives rise $B\mathbb{Z}_2 \to BSU(2) \to BSO(3) \to B^2\mathbb{Z}_2,$
$$
 BSU(2)\to BSO(3) \to B^2\mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
which seems to suggest a fibration of $BSU(2)$ over $B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$

My questions:

> (a) Do (B) and (C) above really suggest a valid fibration of classifying space fibered over another classifying spaces? How do we classify them? Are there similar classifications like Postinikov classes?
>
> (b) The first example (A) and the later (B) and (C) look very different from each other. Are there any relations or generalizations to relate each of them?
>
> (c) In general, given  $B^2M \equiv B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $BG \equiv BSO(3)$ or $BO(3)$, what are other possible fibrations between them (these classifying spaces)?

Comment: (A) is slightly misleading: $H^3(X,M)$ classifies fibrations over X with fiber $B^2M$ and 'structure group' $B^2M$, i.e. "principal $B^2M$-bundles". (You can make that literally true if you model $K(\mathbb{Z}/2, 2)$ by a topological abelian group). In the case (B) and (C), however, you don't have a fiber which can act on itself. You're in the general situation: fibrations over $X$ with fiber $F$ are classified by maps $X \to B\mathrm{hAut}(F)$ where the latter is the classifying space of self weak equivalences of F.

Comment: It may be easier to start with a similar question involving $BO(2)$, $BSO(2)$, $B{\mathbb Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks Igor Belegradek, I also asked https://mathoverflow.net/q/301573/106497

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, yes, your examples are all correct.  However, in example~(B) we just have $O(3)=\{\pm I\}\times SO(3)$ as groups, so your fibration is just the product of 
$$BSO(3)\xrightarrow{1}BSO(3)\to 1$$
 with the path-loop fibration 
$$ B\mathbb{Z}/2\to 1\to B^2\mathbb{Z}/2 . $$
The same happens with $BSO(m)$ and $BO(m)$ whenever $m$ is odd.  When $m$ is even, there is no normal subgroup of order two in $O(m)$, so we cannot do an analogous thing.  However, for any $m$ we have an extension $SO(m)\to O(m)\to \mathbb{Z}/2$ giving a fibration $BSO(m)\to BO(m)\to B\mathbb{Z}/2$, the other way around from your example.

As Dylan mentioned, fibrations with fibre $F$ are classified by maps to $B\text{hAut}(F)$.  If $F$ has a group structure then it acts on itself by translation, giving a map $F\to\text{hAut}(F)$.  In this context we have a homeomorphism $\text{Map}(F,F)=F\times\text{Map}_*(F,F)$ and similarly $\text{hAut}(F)=F\times\text{hAut}_*(F)$, where $\text{hAut}_*(F)$ is the space of based weak equivalences from $F$ to itself.  If $F=K(\mathbb{Z}/2,d)=B^d(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ then for $k>0$ we have $\pi_k(\text{Map}_*(F,F))=[\Sigma^kF,F]=H^d(\Sigma^kF,\mathbb{Z}/2)=0$ (because $\Sigma^kF$ is $(d+k-1)$-connected).  Moreover, in this case we have $\pi_0(\text{Map}_*(F,F))=H^d(F;\mathbb{Z}/2)=\{0,1\}$, with the $0$-component consisting of nullhomotopic maps, and the $1$-component consisting of weak equivalences.  From this we find that the translation map $F\to\text{hAut}(F)$ is a weak equivalence in this case (as well as being a homomorphism of topological groups).  This gives $B\text{hAut}(F)\simeq K(\mathbb{Z}/2,d+1)$, so fibrations with fibre $F$ and base $B$ are classified by maps $B\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,d+1)$, or in other words by Postnikov invariants in $H^{d+1}(B;\mathbb{Z}/2)$.  None of this relies on $B$ being the classifying space of a Lie group, which is a bit of a distraction from the real issues here.

Whenever you have a fibration as above, with total space $E$ say, you get a longer sequence
$$ \dotsb \to \Omega^2B\to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,d-1)\to \Omega E \to \Omega B \to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,d-1) \to E \to B \to K(\mathbb{Z}/2,d)$$
in which any three adjacent terms give a fibration.  In particular, we have some fibrations with Eilenberg-MacLane spaces as the base, and others with Eilenberg-MacLane spaces as the fibre.  All of the examples that we have discussed arise in this way, for suitable choices of $B$ and $d$.

Given a compact Lie group $G$, we could in principle classify fibrations with fibre $BG$ using $B\text{hAut}(BG)$, which is similar to $\text{Map}(BG,BG)$.  If $G$ is an $n$-torus then $BG=K(\mathbb{Z}^n,2)$ and$\text{hAut}(BG)\simeq BG\times GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ by an argument similar to that given above, so this is not too hard to understand.  However, even in the simplest nonabelian case of $G=SU(2)$, the set $[BG,BG]$ is uncountable and has no tractable structure, so this approach is not very useful.  We can instead try to produce extensions $G\to P\to Q$ of topological groups, for various $Q$, and then take classifying spaces to produce fibrations $BG\to BP\to BQ$.  This will not produce all $BG$-fibrations over $BQ$, but it will produce a class of such fibrations that one can reasonably hope to analyse.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! see also mathoverflow.net/q/301573/106497