# Classification of fibrations for classifying spaces $B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $BSO(2)$ or $BO(2)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes, fibre-bundles, classifying-spaces

Thanks to a suggestion by @Igor Belegradek, I am interested also in a simpler problem of [this earlier question 301523](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301523/106497), by knowing what can we say about the classification of fibrations for classifying spaces $B^2M \equiv B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $BG \equiv BSO(2)$ or $BO(2)$.

Here we can take either:

1. $B^2M=B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ as fibers, and $BG=BSO(2)$ (or $BO(2)$) as base space.

or

2. $BG=BSO(2)$ (or $BO(2)$)   as fibers, and $B^2M=B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ as base space.

For example,

**(A)** We consider the  Postinikov classes $\omega \in H^3(BG,M)$. This classifies the fibrations of
$$
B^2M \hookrightarrow BG_\text{{new}} \to BG.
$$
If I understand correctly, the distinct $BG_\text{{new}}$ are determined by the classes of cocycles $\omega \in H^3(BG,M)$.

**(B)** On the other hand, we have $1\to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to Spin(2) \to SO(2) \to 1$, this gives rise $B\mathbb{Z}_2 \to BSpin(2) \to BSO(2) \to B^2\mathbb{Z}_2,$
$$
 BSpin(2) \to BSO(2) \to B^2\mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
which seems to suggest a fibration of $BSpin(2)$ over $B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$

**(C)** On the other hand, we further have $1\to SO(2)  \to O(2) \to \mathbb{Z}_2  \to 1$, this gives rise $BSO(2) \to BO(2) \to B \mathbb{Z}_2,$
which seems not to suggest any related fibration pertinent to my question?

My questions:

> (a) Do (B) and (C) above really suggest a valid fibration of classifying space fibered over another classifying spaces? How do we classify them? Are there similar classifications like Postinikov classes?
>
> (b) The first example (A) and the later (B) and (C) look very different from each other. Are there any relations or generalizations to relate each of them?
>
> (c) In general, given  $B^2M \equiv B^2\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $BG \equiv BSO(2)$ or $BO(2)$, what are other possible fibrations between them (these classifying spaces)?

Comment: I don't think it is useful to have this as a separate question from 301523.